Is there a way to fix my fill method for my Canvas tool?
I'm using a modified Canvas tool in python. It's based on this version:
https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/pyside6-bitmap-graphics/
I left my fill methods below.
def flood_fill(canvas, x, y, old_color, new_color):
    # Get the color of the pixel at position (x, y)
    pixel_color = canvas.pixmap().toImage().pixelColor(x, y).getRgb()[:3]

    # Check if the pixel color matches the old_color
    if pixel_color == old_color:
        # Fill the pixel with the new_color
        canvas.pixmap().toImage().setPixelColor(x, y, QtGui.QColor(*new_color))

        # Recursively fill neighboring pixels
        flood_fill(canvas, x + 1, y, old_color, new_color)
        flood_fill(canvas, x - 1, y, old_color, new_color)
        flood_fill(canvas, x, y + 1, old_color, new_color)
        flood_fill(canvas, x, y - 1, old_color, new_color)

    def fill_shape(self, x, y):
        if not self.fill_mode:
            return

        pixmap = self.pixmap()
        image = pixmap.toImage()

        # Check if coordinates are within the bounds of the image
        if x < 0 or x >= image.width() or y < 0 or y >= image.height():
            return

        old_color = image.pixelColor(x, y).getRgb()[:3]  # Extract RGB values from image
        new_color = self.fill_color  # Get fill color in RGB format

        if old_color == new_color:
            return

        flood_fill(self, x, y, old_color, new_color)

        self.setPixmap(pixmap)

I tried changing the format type to a numpy array but it didn't work so I tried rgb values and it's not giving me errors but the code just finishes.
